# How to update OpenSSL on centos 7.2?

Tags: openssl, centos7

I am using centos 7.2, I would like to update openssl,current version is as follow:

```
[root@i001 ~]# rpm -qa|grep openssl
openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4.x86_64
```

I tried to download SRPM package in fedora repertory,

```
openssl-1.0.2d-2.fc23.src.rpm
```

rebuild it and install,but there is something wrong,

```
[root@i001 ~]# yum update openssl
Loaded plugins: axelget, langpacks
No metadata available for base
No metadata available for dockerrepo
No metadata available for elrepo
No metadata available for epel
No metadata available for extras
No metadata available for local
No metadata available for mariadb
No metadata available for nginx
No metadata available for remi-php70
No metadata available for remi-php70-test
No metadata available for remi-safe
No metadata available for salt-2015.8
No metadata available for updates
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2d-2.el7.centos will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2d-2.el7.centos for package: 1:openssl-1.0.2d-2.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) for package: 1:openssl-1.0.2d-2.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4 for package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4.x86_64
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2d-2.el7.centos will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: crypto-policies for package: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2d-2.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4 will be updated
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.2d-2.el7.centos will be an update
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2d-2.el7.centos will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: crypto-policies for package: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2d-2.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2d-2.el7.centos.x86_64 (local)
           Requires: crypto-policies
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What should I do?

Comment: This question is off topic here and should be asked on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need to update this critical library ?

Have you read [Backporting Security Fixes](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting/) ?